# How do 16bit RAM chips arrange for ECC memory?

Tags: memory

So there are some DIMM with 16bit chips, which only need 4 chips for a normal 64 bit bank, but ECC bank should have 72bit width, it's not a problem with 8 or 4 bit chips, however with 16bit chips, how do they get the extra 8bit?

Answer (score 0):

Not all chips on a module are necessarily the same. Also, if you have a dual rank module, one 16-bit chip could be split between two ranks. There are various arrangements possible.